# Search as user types functionality flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What is the functionality called where a user types into a search bar and API calls are made as the user types and they never have to click search?

I don't want a typeahead, I want to specifically be able to send off http requests as the user types in a search bar and return the results as a number of cards individual below the search bar.

The flutter_typeahead package is similar but I want to be able to control what happens with the results.

Answer (score 0):

well you can do something like this

```dart
double waitForInputInterval = 300 // ms
double lastKeyStroke = null;

void search(String searchedTerm) {
  final now = DateTime.now();


    // wait 300ms before sending api requests;
   if( lastKeyStroke != null && now.millisecond- lastKeyStroke <  waitForInputInterval ) {
      // send api request setState and other stuff
    }
   // for the first time
    else {
      lastKeyStroke = DateTime.now().millisecond;

     }
}


/// inside build

TextField(
onChange: search
)
```